# MINGW / Cross Compile : Static linking of libquadmath in Fortran Code

Tags: linux, windows, gcc, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I have to cross compile a FORTRAN code from Linux to Windows (32bit) using mingw-w64. Therefore, I am using mingw-w64 7 (gcc 9.3.0) on Ubuntu 20.04/x86_64.

As a minimal testing example, I used the following piece of code:

```
module mykinds
use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
implicit none
private
public sp, dp, ep, qp
integer, parameter :: sp = REAL_KINDS(1)
integer, parameter :: dp = REAL_KINDS(2)
integer, parameter :: ep = REAL_KINDS(3)
integer, parameter :: qp = REAL_KINDS(4)
end module mykinds

program quadtest
use mykinds
implicit none
real(qp), parameter :: pi = 4*atan(1.0_qp)

write(*,*) sp,dp,ep,qp
write(*,*) pi
end program quadtest
```

In order to avoid dependencies on GCC libraries, I compiled the code using the following command line:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran -static-libgfortran -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lquadmath -Wl,-Bdynamic quadtest.f90 -o a.exe
```

Now, if I check the output file using `objdump` I get:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-objdump -p a.exe
...
    DLL Name: libquadmath-0.dll
    vma:  Hint/Ord Member-Name Bound-To
    4092c      75  quadmath_snprintf
    40940      87  strtoflt128

 0004003c   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Unfortunately, this includes the `libquadmath` again as DLL, although it should be linked as static library. Checking for its existence gives:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran -print-file-name=libquadmath.a
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libquadmath.a
```

Comment: Try also adding the `-static` flag.

Comment: The aim is to only get the gcc/gfortran related libraries statically linked, all others, even if the exists in both, dynamic and static, should be used in their dynamic form.